# Slab cache affecting used memory much more than /proc/meminfo suggests

Tags: linux, memory, aws, out-of-memory

I'm dealing with a memory issue that is affecting hundreds of machines in AWS. They are i3.4xl instances with 120GB of RAM. There is a Java database server running inside a Docker container that consumes the majority of the RAM, but I'm observing the "used memory" metric reporting much higher than the usage of that process.

```
~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         122878      105687       11608        1221        5583       14285
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Here's a snapshot of top. Out of the 108GB of used memory, only 77GB is occupied by the database.

```
top - 18:21:25 up 310 days, 15:48,  1 user,  load average: 23.78, 20.90, 24.30
Tasks: 284 total,   2 running, 282 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.4 us,  3.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 83.5 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.9 si,  1.1 st
KiB Mem : 12582788+total,  7280872 free, 10839378+used, 10153232 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 14414696 avail Mem 

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                         
 45338 root      20   0 88.304g 0.077t  24460 S 396.7 65.9   4962:44 java                                                                            
  1353 consul    20   0   53784  30068      0 S   1.3  0.0  10030:05 consul                                                                          
 82080 root      24   4  979740  46128   8548 S   1.3  0.0   6:46.95 aws                                                                             
  2941 dd-agent  20   0  194848  23548   3068 S   1.0  0.0   1293:05 python                                                                          
    83 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0 290:30.49 ksoftirqd/15                                                                    
   503 root      20   0  147352  98228  87492 S   0.3  0.1 994:49.08 systemd-journal                                                                 
   964 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   1031:29 xfsaild/nvme0n1                                                                 
  1405 root      20   0 1628420  48796  16588 S   0.3  0.0 533:50.58 dockerd                                                                         
  2963 dd-agent  20   0 4184188 241520   1196 S   0.3  0.2 168:24.64 java                                                                            
 28797 xray      20   0 3107132 236288   4724 S   0.3  0.2 150:04.44 xray                                                                            
116185 root      20   0 1722788  13012   6348 S   0.3  0.0  53:54.38 amazon-ssm-agen                                                                 
     1 root      20   0   38728   6144   3308 S   0.0  0.0   2:41.84 systemd                                                                         
     2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0 399:59.14 kthreadd
```

And /proc/meminfo:

```
~# cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       125827888 kB
MemFree:         5982300 kB
MemAvailable:   14354644 kB
Buffers:            2852 kB
Cached:          9269636 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         86468892 kB
Inactive:        6778036 kB
Active(anon):   83977260 kB
Inactive(anon):  1259020 kB
Active(file):    2491632 kB
Inactive(file):  5519016 kB
Unevictable:        3660 kB
Mlocked:            3660 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:            220968 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      83978456 kB
Mapped:           182596 kB
Shmem:           1259060 kB
Slab:            2122036 kB
SReclaimable:    1131528 kB
SUnreclaim:       990508 kB
KernelStack:       48416 kB
PageTables:       183468 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    62913944 kB
Committed_AS:   89880700 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     28672 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     4868096 kB
DirectMap2M:    120961024 kB
DirectMap1G:     4194304 kB
```

I had previously made some changes to try and reclaim the slab cache more aggressively by setting this:

```
~# cat /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure 
1000
```

The slab memory in /proc/meminfo used to report 15GB+, but now it stays around 2GB. Here's the slabtop output (added in an edit, some time after the drop cache below when memory had started filling up again):

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 7068193 / 7395845 (95.6%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 158330 / 158330 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 81 / 128 (63.3%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 2121875.02K / 2188049.35K (97.0%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.29K / 8.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
1465206 1464982  99%    0.38K  35375       42    566000K mnt_cache
1360044 1360044 100%    0.19K  32383       42    259064K dentry
1175936 1107199  94%    0.03K   9187      128     36748K kmalloc-32
1056042 1055815  99%    0.10K  27078       39    108312K buffer_head
732672 727789  99%    1.06K  24606       30    787392K xfs_inode
462213 453665  98%    0.15K   8721       53     69768K xfs_ili
333284 333250  99%    0.57K   6032       56    193024K radix_tree_node
173056 117508  67%    0.06K   2704       64     10816K kmalloc-64
 90336  31039  34%    0.12K   1414       64     11312K kmalloc-128
 82656  23185  28%    0.19K   1972       42     15776K kmalloc-192
 58328  40629  69%    0.50K   1012       64     32384K kmalloc-512
 51476  51476 100%    0.12K    758       68      6064K kernfs_node_cache
 45440  15333  33%    0.25K    713       64     11408K kmalloc-256
 21250  21250 100%    0.05K    250       85      1000K ftrace_event_field
 20706  20298  98%    0.04K    203      102       812K ext4_extent_status
 19779  18103  91%    0.55K    347       57     11104K inode_cache
 18600  18600 100%    0.61K    363       52     11616K proc_inode_cache
 14800  13964  94%    0.20K    371       40      2968K vm_area_struct
 14176   6321  44%    1.00K    443       32     14176K kmalloc-1024
 12006  12006 100%    0.09K    261       46      1044K trace_event_file
 11776  11776 100%    0.01K     23      512        92K kmalloc-8
```

However, it still appears that the slab cache is causing the used memory to be high. I believe this because I can drop it:

```
~# echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Then you see this:

```
~# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         122878       82880       36236        1245        3761       37815
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Over 20GB was freed by dropping the slab cache despite it only showing 2GB of memory in /proc/meminfo. Here's the new /proc/meminfo:

```
~# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       125827888 kB
MemFree:        34316592 kB
MemAvailable:   38394188 kB
Buffers:            6652 kB
Cached:          5726320 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         85651988 kB
Inactive:        4084612 kB
Active(anon):   84007364 kB
Inactive(anon):  1283596 kB
Active(file):    1644624 kB
Inactive(file):  2801016 kB
Unevictable:        3660 kB
Mlocked:            3660 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:            260096 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      84008564 kB
Mapped:           194628 kB
Shmem:           1283636 kB
Slab:             601176 kB
SReclaimable:     401788 kB
SUnreclaim:       199388 kB
KernelStack:       48496 kB
PageTables:       183564 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    62913944 kB
Committed_AS:   89815920 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     28672 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     4868096 kB
DirectMap2M:    120961024 kB
DirectMap1G:     4194304 kB
```

So I guess my question is just why does this happen and how can I prevent the slab cache from affecting used memory so much? It eventually causes the Java server to get oom-killed but also probably prevents the page cache from being more effective. The Java server does touch a lot (millions) of files in the file system (XFS), so that may be related, but I don't understand why the metrics reported don't line up. Once again, this affects hundreds of machines that are configured in the same way.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: good question! highly non-obvious how dropping caches would manage to increase the figure under "available" by over 20GB.

Comment: It _sounds_ as if there is an allocation which uses `__get_free_pages()` directly (not `kmalloc()`), which is owned by some much smaller, droppable slab structures.  aka a bad idea.

Comment: You sound quite focused on slabs, I wonder if you have run `slabtop`.

Comment: "[...] unknown amounts of data attached to each object that might be written back. There is, he said, a lot of memory hidden in places where the memory-management subsystem has no idea how to find it." Not sure what that refers to. https://lwn.net/Articles/752552/

Comment: "Chinner said that XFS does the majority of its metadata writeback by way of shrinkers, but also all of its page-reclaim work. The XFS cache structure is too complicated to express in the page cache, so the page cache is not used for this purpose." Hmm. It seems this could be filesystem-specific, I really think you need to say what filesystem you are using :-).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I did run slabtop, and the output was consistent with /proc/meminfo, showing around 2GB of total stuff across the dentry/inode caches and other small things.

As for file system, I am indeed using XFS, so I'll look into that a bit more.

Comment: I edited the line about "nothing explains the 108G" since I was confused by it, hope that's ok.

Comment: Lol at 1465206x `mnt_cache`. I guess you have a *lot* of containers other than the memory hog! https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/namespace.c#L203